# Sending submit data into Flask without page refresh

Tags: python, flask

**Intro:**
I'm making an app with many records that allows you to have a ranking/upvote system
Pic attached:[image: this is how UI looks like]

**The problem:** I face is that each time I press 'Upvote +1', the page gets refreshed - and I want to solve it.

Here is my **Flask** app:

```
def form():
   form = LoginForm()
   value = 0
   records = Row.query.order_by(Row.id.desc())

   if form.validate_on_submit(): #if we submit something -> pick the ID of the item
      for i in dict(request.form):
        id_of_record_to_change = i


      item = Row.query.filter_by(id=id_of_record_to_change) #filter item by the ID
      new_value = item.first().rating + 1 #add +1 to the rating value
      item.first().rating = new_value
      db.session.commit() #record to database

   return render_template('form.html', records=records, form=form, value=value)
```

Here is my **html:**

```
    {{form.csrf_token }}
    
    {% for item in records %}
    {{ item.rating }}

    <input type="hidden" id="intval" name="intval" value="{{ item.rating }}"> <!-- rating we want to increase -->
    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="{{ item.id }}"> <!-- ID we want to pass -->
    <input type="submit" id="target" name = "{{ item.id }}" value="Upvote +1"> <!-- submit action -->            
    {% endfor %}
   </form>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/jquery/

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/talking-to-python-from-javascript-flask-and-the-fetch-api-e0ef3573c451

Comment: @thebjorn - thank you for your response! Tbh I got stuck a bit with this tutorial, but looks like it's close enough to what I needed

Comment: @RaniSharim - thank you very much! Your tutorial helped me resolve the problem - pls add your comment as an answer so I could select it :-)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve my problem thanks to @RaniSharim who posted a link to the proper tutorial

Here is how my code changed:

1. In **Flask app** I added the following route to 'get/send/process' the data:

```
######## Data fetch ############
@app.route('/getdata/<index_no>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def data_get(index_no):
    
    if request.method == 'GET': # POST request
        item = Row.query.filter_by(id=index_no) #filter item by the ID
        new_value = item.first().rating + 1 #add +1 to the rating value
        item.first().rating = new_value
        db.session.commit() #record to database
        return '%s'%(new_value)
#################################
```

2. And my **html file** now looks like this:

```
    {% for item in records %}
    <hr>
    <button id ="{{item.id}}" onclick="SomeFunc()"> {{ item.rating }}</button>
<!---  ################################  -->
    <script >
        function SomeFunc() {
            var button = event.target;
            var element_id = button.id;
            index = element_id
            
            fetch(`/getdata/${index}`)
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.text();
                    
                }).then(function(text) {
                    document.getElementById(index).innerText = ' ' + text;
                });
        } </script>
<!---  ################################  -->
    {% endfor %}
```

In this way we can avoid page reload + we imitate the ranking change with JS

Thanks!